# How to get set select value from localstorage?

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I have the below select component:

```
<label>
{{ "HOME.SELECT" | translate }}
<select #langSelect (change)="translate.use(langSelect.value)" (change)='onOptionsSelected($event)'>
  <option *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" [value]="lang" [selected]="??">
    {{ lang }}</option>
 </select>
</label>
```

In the constructor, the selected language is saved into localstorage as below:

```
constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
  translate.addLangs(["en-US", "fr-FR", "de-DE"]);
  if (localStorage.getItem('language')) {
  translate.setDefaultLang(localStorage.getItem('language'));
  translate.use(localStorage.getItem('language'));
} else {
  translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  translate.use('en');
  localStorage.setItem("language", "en");
}
}
```

How can I set selected index of the   based on the value stored in localstorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add 'value' parameter to select and pass variable to it like below. Assign the value of variable to localstorage value. Assign the same variable to 'selected'.

Updated your code below:

<pre>
  <label>
    {{ "HOME.SELECT" | translate }}
    <select #langSelect (change)="translate.use(langSelect.value)" (change)='onOptionsSelected($event)' value="localStorageValueVariable">
      <option *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" [value]="lang" [selected]="localStorageValueVariable">
        {{ lang }}</option>
     </select>
    </label>
</pre>
```